# Stick div element to the bottom of the header element

Tags: html, css, header

Well, we all use headers, and usually use `position: fixed;` to fix the header to the top of the page. But what to do if we want 2 headers, one big, main one, and one smaller, for secondary links, for example? I made some research and found tip to use `position: relative;` in the parent element style (header in our case) and `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` in the child element style (div). This, however, unsticks the header from the top. Okay, but we can try adding `margin-top: (height of the header);` to the `div` stylesheet. This one is probably gonna work on your current resolution. Perhaps, on the another device the height of the header will not be the same, so second header (div) will be moved too much.
This is what I imagine while talking about this.

[image: illustration]

It is possible to solve like this, but the size will still change depending on the resolution of the device:

[image: incorrect solution]

Finally, my question is - **How to properly stick `div` element to the bottom of the `header` element?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get away with using `position: sticky` or `position: fixed` on both, you just have to set the `top` property of the main header to `0` so it stays at the top of the page and the `top` property of the second header to the height of the main header. That height can be a fixed value like `10px` or a relative value like `10%` or `10vh`.

To use `10%`, you'll have to make sure the ancestor of both headers has `position: relative` and takes up the full height you expect. For that reason, `10vh` is easier - it's always 10% of the viewport's height no matter the stacking context for the current element.

```css
/* Reset margins - you don't need this, it's just for the snippet. */
* { margin: 0; }

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10vh;
  position: sticky;
}

#primary-header {
  top: 0;
  background-color: green;
} 

#secondary-header {
  top: 10vh;
  background-color: red;
}

section {
  height: 5000px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, white);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header class="header" id="primary-header">Header 1</header>
<div class="header" id="secondary-header">Header 2</div>
<section>Scroll down...</section>
```

For a more complex case, you can use the [`calc()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to sum the expected height, padding, margins, etc of the first header to get a `top` value for the second header:

```css
/* Reset margins - you don't need this, it's just for the snippet. */
* { margin: 0; }

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10vh;
  position: sticky;
}

#primary-header {
  top: 0.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  background-color: green;
} 

#secondary-header {
  /* 10vh for height, 2rem for padding (top and bottom), 0.5rem for margin. */
  top: calc(10vh + 2.5rem);
  background-color: red;
}

section {
  height: 5000px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, white);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header class="header" id="primary-header">Header 1</header>
<div class="header" id="secondary-header">Header 2</div>
<section>Scroll down...</section>
```

Comment: Sometimes you use paddings in the first header, so that also has to be taken into consideration 

Comment: Sure, I added a second example with some extra considerations for when you're not just defining a `height` for the main header.

Comment: Well, `calc()` function makes it easier)  
Thanks for the answer